# Symfony2 injecting services container & security

Tags: symfony

I wish to inject the services security.context & service_container in a controller. It is possible ?

here my controller :

```
<?php 
 ...
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
 ...
class ApiProtectedController extends Controller {
    protected $container;
    protected $securityContext;

    function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }
    ...
}
```

And my services declaration

```
api_protected_controller:
    class: MyProject\ApiBundle\Controller\ApiProtectedController
    arguments: [@service_container, @security.context]

//here an example of something working fine 
wsse.api.security.authentication.provider:
    class:  MyProject\ApiBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider
    arguments: ['', %kernel.cache_dir%/security/nonces, @service_container]
```

the error returned :

```
 Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyProject\ApiBundle\Controller\ApiProtectedController::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,
```

my goal is to get in my controller the token injected in `securityContext` by `wsseprovider`, do you think it's possible ?

Comment: what happens if you do not extend basic controller?

Comment: Post the route that is calling the controller.  I'm guessing that you have not defined the controller as a service in your routing file.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: Actually, if you do extend the basic controller, there is no need to inject the container. It is already available through `$this->container`, and security context is available through `$this->get('security.context')`. So is any other service.

Comment: Do you really need to inject the container? It is a very bad practice. You should only inject the services you need => http://danielribeiro.org/blog/injecting-the-container-a-bad-practice-that-you-should-avoid/

Comment: @FlorentMorselli no I don't, but it is a service and I would to know how inject services so it's an example catch in wsselistener from cookbook

Comment: @Cerad 
in services.yml
services:
  api_protected_controller:
    class: MyProject\ApiBundle\Controller\ApiProtectedController
this is not a service ?

Comment: @dmnptr I need this class as a controller, because each action function return my api datas. what kind of controller are you thinking ?

Comment: What are you extending here - ` extends Controller'?

Comment: User1847729 - It's a service but the router will still treat it as a regular class and new it unless you follow the procedure in the link I posted.  Of course, as @dmnptr has said, you don't really need to do this for a controller.  But it is nice to know how.

Comment: @Cerad Ok it's clearer now, thanks